# Fix awkward transition in bootstrap collapse and remove visited link styling in .well

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The div class="well" looks correct after it is completely opened, but it has some sort of animation as it scrolls open that still has a border and a different colored background. I can't figure out how to change that. Can anyone help?

Also, the links inside of the div class="well", after they have been visited then they turn blue with an underline by default. How do I remove the underline and visited color here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

http://codepen.io/aahmed2/pen/ZOqZgg?editors=0100

Above is a link to my Codepen so you can see exactly what is happening. Try clicking "Cooperia" under the cattle section and you will see the weird transition. If you select "About" then return back to my Codepen you will see the default bootstrap styling that I can't figure out how to remove.

```css
a {
  color: #000;
}
a:hover {
  color: #d00000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.animal-disease-main h3 {
  color: #fff;
  background: #c1c0be;
  padding: 10px;
}
.animal-disease-main a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.animal-disease-main .collapse .well {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px 29px;
}
.collapse .well a {
  padding: 0;
}
.collapse .well a:visted {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
a[role="button"]:focus,
a[role="button"]:active {
  color: #d00000;
}
a[role="button"]:visted {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="animal-disease-main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Cattle</h3>
      <a href="/health-resources/anthrax.html">Anthrax</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/bovine-tuberculosis.html">Bovine Tuberculosis</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/brucellosis.html">Brucellosis</a>
      <br>
      <a class="animal-health-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#calf-scours" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="calf-scours">
                Calf Scours
            </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="calf-scours">
        <div class="well">
          <a href="http://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0015/50208/treating_calf_scours_-_primefact_135-final.pdf" target="_blank">Fact Sheet</a>
          <br>
          <a href="https://www.ag.ndsu.edu/pubs/ansci/beef/as776.pdf" target="_blank">Fact Sheet 2</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.cattlenetwork.com/cattle-resources/baby-calf-health/Calf-Scours-Causes-prevention-and-treatment-121277154.html" target="_blank">Causes, Prevention, Treatment</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.extension.umn.edu/agriculture/dairy/calves-and-heifers/ten-strategies-to-battle-calf-scours/" target="_blank">Strategies for Calf Scours</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://msue.anr.msu.edu/news/calf_scours_signs_treatment_and_prevention_part_2" target="_blank">Symptoms, Treatment, Prevention</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www1.agric.gov.ab.ca/$department/deptdocs.nsf/all/faq8072" target="_blank">FAQ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#cooperia" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cooperia">
                Cooperia
            </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="cooperia">
        <div class="well">
          <a href="http://cal.vet.upenn.edu/projects/merialsp/Trichosp/trich_8.htm" target="_blank">About</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0015/50208/treating_calf_scours_-_primefact_135-final.pdf" target="_blank">Fact Sheet</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://parasitipedia.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2632&Itemid=2910" target="_blank">Biology, Prevention, and Control</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.progressivecattle.com/topics/herd-health/4676-cooperia-study-shows-ineffective-dewormers-costly-effects" target="_blank">Inneffective Wormers' Cost Effects</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/cryptosporidium.html">Cryptosporidium</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/fmd.html">Foot and Mouth Disease</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/leptospirosis.html">Leptospirosis</a>
      <br>
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#neosporosis" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="neosporosis">
                Neosporosis
            </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="neosporosis">
        <div class="well">
          <a href="http://www.ars.usda.gov/News/docs.htm?docid=11007" target="_blank">Animal Overview</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.merckvetmanual.com/mvm/generalized_conditions/neosporosis/overview_of_neosporosis.html" target="_blank">Disease Facts</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.thecattlesite.com/diseaseinfo/222/neosporosis/" target="_blank">Cattle</a>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#pink-eye" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pink-eye">
                Pink Eye
            </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="pink-eye">
        <div class="well">
          <a href="http://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/103904/pinkeye-in-cattle.pdf" target="_blank">Fact Sheet</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://beef.unl.edu/pinkeye-in-cattle" target="_blank">Overview</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://beef.unl.edu/cattleproduction/controllingflies" target="_blank">Fly Control</a>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/vesicular-stomatitis.html">Vesicular Stomatitis</a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Goats and Sheep</h3>
      <a href="/health-resources/anthrax.html">Anthrax</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/brucellosis.html">Brucellosis</a>
      <br>
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#cooperia2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cooperia2">
                Cooperia
            </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="cooperia2">
        <div class="well">
          <a href="http://cal.vet.upenn.edu/projects/merialsp/Trichosp/trich_8.htm" target="_blank">About</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.dpi.nsw.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0015/50208/treating_calf_scours_-_primefact_135-final.pdf" target="_blank">Fact Sheet</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://parasitipedia.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2632&Itemid=2910" target="_blank">Biology, Prevention, and Control</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.progressivecattle.com/topics/herd-health/4676-cooperia-study-shows-ineffective-dewormers-costly-effects" target="_blank">Inneffective Wormers' Cost Effects</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/cryptosporidium.html">Cryptosporidium</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/fmd.html">Foot and Mouth Disease</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/leptospirosis.html">Leptospirosis</a>
      <br>
      <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#neosporosis2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="neosporosis2">
                Neosporosis
            </a>
      <div class="collapse" id="neosporosis2">
        <div class="well">
          <a href="http://www.ars.usda.gov/News/docs.htm?docid=11007" target="_blank">Animal Overview</a>
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.merckvetmanual.com/mvm/generalized_conditions/neosporosis/overview_of_neosporosis.html" target="_blank">Disease Facts</a>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/vesicular-stomatitis.html">Vesicular Stomatitis</a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Horses</h3>
      <a href="/health-resources/anthrax.html">Anthrax</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/leptospirosis.html">Leptospirosis</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/vesicular-stomatitis.html">Vesicular Stomatitis</a>

      <h3>Pigs</h3>
      <a href="/health-resources/anthrax.html">Anthrax</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/brucellosis.html">Brucellosis</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/fmd.html">Foot and Mouth Disease</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/leptospirosis.html">Leptospirosis</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/swine-flu.html">Swine Flu</a> 

      <h3>Poultry</h3>
      <a href="/health-resources/anthrax.html">Anthrax</a>
      <br>
      <a href="/health-resources/avian-influenza.html">Avian Influenza</a>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the animation behaviour you should go for:

```
.collapsing{
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
```

remember that this animation includes 3 states

.collapse -> .collapsing -> .collapse in

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

So if you want to change the default Bootstrap animation that's where you should doing some work.

About the text style after a link has been visited, that's in

```
a:visited { 
  color: "your-default-color";
  text-decoration: none;
}
```